# openpyxl - error importing in Python script

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a python script at work (that I didn't write) which cycles through a folder of SQL scripts, condenses the SQL queries into one line each and adds them to an Excel document (along with other columns).   This script always worked fine until this week when my work computer died.  I got a new one, installed miniconda and then installed openpyxl by opening Anaconda prompt and:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

(pip3 install didn't work).

Most of my Python scripts work fine but this one does not.  It is throwing an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'range' from 'openpyxl.compat' (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\compat\__init__.py)
```

I tried to drill down into the libraries/site-packages to see the details, and I don't see 'range' listed anymore in the **init** file for that path.  Maybe they got rid of it?   Does anyone know what the suitable alternative is for that?  To be honest I can't even tell where it is being used in the script, but when i take out that import statement it runs but it results in a blank Excel output file.  So clearly it is used somewhere

```
import sqlparse
import glob
import sys
import regex as re
import os
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.compat import range

def main():

    path = "C:/my_path\sql_files*"
    fileList = glob.glob(path)

    TABLE_ID = 0
    # TABLE_NM = ''
    # STEP_ID = 0
    STEP_TYPE = ''

    # workFile = open('C:/Dev\DataWarehouseTesting\workfile.txt', 'w')
    # wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('workfile.xlsx')

    wb = Workbook()
    ws1 = wb.active
    ws1.title = "auto_tests"

    # Adding the headers for the Excel sheet.
    ws1['A1'] = 'TABLE_ID'
    ws1['B1'] = 'TABLE_NM'
    ws1['C1'] = 'TEST_TABLE_NM'
    ws1['D1'] = 'STEP_ID'
    ws1['E1'] = 'STEP_TYPE'
    ws1['F1'] = 'SQL_SCRIPT'

    def createSQL(pTABLE_ID, pTABLE_NM, pTEST_TABLE_NM, pSTEP_ID, pSTEP_TYPE, pSqlStr):
        pSqlStr = pSqlStr.replace('\'','"')
        sliceLeft = pSqlStr[:6]
        if sliceLeft == 'SELECT':
            pSTEP_TYPE = 'T'
        elif sliceLeft != 'SELECT':
            pSTEP_TYPE = 'P'

        max_row = ws1.max_row
        nextRow = str(max_row + 1)

        ws1['A' + nextRow] = str(pTABLE_ID)
        ws1['B' + nextRow] = pTABLE_NM
        ws1['C' + nextRow] = pTEST_TABLE_NM
        ws1['D' + nextRow] = str(pSTEP_ID)
        ws1['E' + nextRow] = pSTEP_TYPE
        ws1['F' + nextRow] = pSqlStr



    def createTableTestSQL(mFile, TABLE_ID,  TABLE_NM,STEP_ID, STEP_TYPE):
        mText = mFile.read()
        mSqls = sqlparse.split(mText)
        for mSql in mSqls:
            STEP_ID += 1
            sqlStr = str(mSql.replace('\n',' '))
            sqlStr = re.sub('--([^\s]+)',' ',sqlStr)
            sqlStr = sqlparse.format(sqlStr, strip_comments=True)
            if STEP_ID == 1:
                TEST_TABLE_NM = sqlStr.replace("DROP TABLE ", "").replace(";", "")
            createSQL(TABLE_ID, TABLE_NM, TEST_TABLE_NM, STEP_ID, STEP_TYPE, sqlStr)


    for filename in fileList:
        if filename.endswith('.sql'):
            mFile = open(filename,'r')
            TABLE_ID += 1
            TABLE_NM = os.path.split(filename)[1].replace('.sql','')
            #TEST_TABLE_NM = ''
            STEP_ID = 0
            createTableTestSQL(mFile, TABLE_ID, TABLE_NM, STEP_ID, STEP_TYPE)
            mFile.close()

    wb.save(filename='test_data_TR.xlsx')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Why are you trying to import `range` in your code? It doesn't look like you use it.

Comment: @CharlieClark  that's what I thought, but when I take it out it just results in a blank Excel file, when there should be rows after cycling through the SQL scripts

Comment: That will be something else, nothing related to the import.

Comment: got it, ill keep searching for the cause.  thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?